# Is my proof acceptable? $\rho(\tau\sigma)\leq min\{\rho(\tau),\rho(\sigma)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Theorem 1.3. Let $\sigma : U\to V$ be a linear map from an $m$-dimensional vector space to an $n$-dimensional one.  The rank $\rho$ of $\sigma$ satisfies $\rho(\sigma)\le \min\{m,n\}$.

Prove: If $\sigma : U\to V$ and $\tau : V\to W$ are linear maps, then 
the rank of the composition satisfies $\rho(\tau\sigma)\leq min\{\rho(\tau),\rho(\sigma)\}$.

Proof:

Define the following linear transformations $\sigma$ and $\tau$ such that $\sigma:U\rightarrow V$ and $\tau: V\rightarrow W$. Let $\rho$ mean rank and let $dimU=m$, $dimV=n$, $dimW=q$. By Theorem 1.3., 
\begin{align}
\rho(\tau\sigma)\leq min\{m,q\}; \rho(\sigma)\leq min\{m,n\}; \rho(\tau)\leq min\{\rho(\sigma),q\}
\end{align}
Thus, $\rho(\sigma)\leq m$ and $\rho(\tau)\leq q$. Therefore, $\rho(\tau\sigma)\leq min\{\rho(\tau),\rho(\sigma)\}$.

Comment: Theorem 1.3 as stated, is not true: we only have $\rho(\sigma) \le\min(m, n) $, for we can take $\sigma$ as a low rank map, e.g. $\sigma=0$..

Comment: just edited. thank you. now is this acceptable?

Comment: What is $\sigma$ a map from and to? Same question for $\tau$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement is not true: $\rho(\tau)\le \min\{\rho(\sigma),q\}$.

What is true, is that for the restriction to the image of $\sigma$,
$\rho(\tau|_{\sigma(U)})\le \operatorname{dim}(\sigma(U))$. This is what you need to make the proof work.